# cakephp created query for exact date

Tags: php, database, cakephp, model

Trying to figure out how to find all records from database that were created on a specific day but I'm having a hard time coming up with the necessary conditions.  This is what I have so far:

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-11-25');
$users = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.created > ' => $date)));
```

But this is giving me more than just the specified day.  How can I adjust the condition so that it returns all users that were created *only* on November 25th?

Comment: is this also giving dates for "2012-11-24" ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a greater than symbol in it.

```
$users = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.created > ' => $date)));
```

try without:

```
$users = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.created' => $date)));
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the CakeTime method for this or manually assert that you only check on the date part of this particular day.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/time.html#CakeTime::dayAsSql

```
'conditions' => CakeTime::dayAsSql($date, 'created')
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing around, I finally was able to get it to work.  Hopefully this can help somebody else out there that runs across the same situation:

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-11-25');
$users = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => CakeTime::dayAsSql($date, $date, 'User.created')));
```

The key was making sure to provide the $date twice.